# How to close a modal window after a save in Asp.NET WebForms

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, webforms

I have some javascript code on my main page that opens a popup when a link is clicked on:

```
<script language="javascript">  

function OpenResidentialAddressWin(subscriberContactRelationGid, routeId, btn) {
    window.showModalDialog("SubscriberResidentialAddress.aspx" + BuildQueryStringValuesForSubscriber(subscriberContactRelationGid, routeId, returntxtReceiptDate().value), this, strWindowFeatures + ";scroll:no;dialogWidth:442px;dialogHeight:350px");
    location.href = location.href;
}

</script>
```

So the above code opens up the page SubscriberResidentialAddress.aspx in a modal window (as well as passing a number of variables into this page)

Now this page is arranged in such a way that it either displays or edits information. (These are in separate divs that are displayed or hidden dependign on what buttons have just been pressed in the window).

Currently after a user makes a save to the information on the page it switches to display mode. Instead I want to close the modal window completely and reload the main page.

A colleague suggsested that I use a literal control on the aspx page of the modal window and write javascript to it after a successful save has been carried out. So I placed the following in the head section of the SubscriberResidentialAddress.aspx page:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litCloseWind"></asp:Literal>
```

And then in the code behind in the function that is called when a save is carried out

```
  protected void btnAddSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

////// code related to saving

 if (status.IsSuccessful)
            {
                litCloseWind.Text = "<script>this.close()</script>";
                Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri, false);
            }


}
```

I have tried the above and also litCloseWind.Text = "window.close()"; but neither were successful in closing the modal window after a save is carried out.

Is this plan logically sound and have I just made an error somewhere or was this a bad way of doing it to begin with?

Comment: I'm not saying it was a bad idea to begin with, I don't know exactly what you need to do, but I would advice you to not make popups which work with actual browser windows but rather make floating `div` elements appear on top of other things, simply because it is highly probable that some browser somewhere (and I'm talking about `Chrome`, `Firefox`, etc.) will function very differently from what you experimented while developing the app on IE (for instance: they will not allow a popup to appear in the first place)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. This is some legacy system where this is used all over the place for an internal site that will only ever be viewed in Internet Explorer. I'm sure there are lots of things that aren't done correctly in it but redesigning it now is unfortunately not the priority :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you register a script here, like this:

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "CLOSEWINDOW", "window.close();");
```

No need of putting any Literal Control here.

So your code will look something like this:

```
protected void btnAddSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (status.IsSuccessful)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "CLOSEWINDOW", "window.close();");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried replacing my code with this but it doesn't seem to work either. It hits it in the debugger but the window doesn't close after it.

Comment: Sorry i missed the ModalDialog, i think it is something which is not possible easily but you can try this post, may be it will work: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/43569/how-to-close-a-modal-using-javascript-from-code-behind

Comment: Thanks. I tried that. Now though it crashes with the following error: "JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'commitPopup' of undefined or null reference".